# program a Firefox extension to download a page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to apply a regex to a page whose URL only my extension is going to know. How do I program a Firefox extension to download the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found! "To load from file://, http://, chrome://, resource:// and other URLs directly, use XMLHttpRequest or nsIChannel (example)." - [File I/O](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Code_snippets:File_I/O)